# How to paginate when page using POST requests, in turbogers?

Tags: python-2.7, turbogears2, turbogears

I've been trying to paginate a search results page. Which uses POST requests to submit my search form.

I just included the parameters in the pager function and it uses GET method as default.

```
"<a href="${tg.url('/results',dict(request.args_params, page=tmpl_context.paginators.results.first_page))}">«</a>"
${tmpl_context.paginators.leads.pager()}
"<a href="${tg.url('/results',dict(request.args_params,page=tmpl_context.paginators.results.last_page))}">»</a>"
```

With this code, while I'm trying to navigate to another page on the pager, showing the error:

> KeyError("No key 'filter': Not an HTML form submission (Content-Type: text/plain)",)

Python: 2.7
TurboGears: 2.3.12

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be trying to access `tg.request.POST` from your controller action but as you use `<a href="${tg.url('/results' ...` to create those links they will be `GET` requests which can't have `POST` params.

If that's the case I suggest you just don't use `tg.request.POST` but use `tg.request.args_params` instead which should work for both `POST` and `GET` requests.